# Can we startForegroundServie from an exact alarm's receiver in the background?

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-alarms, android-background

In one of the **exemptions** of the "cannot start foreground service from background" restriction, the doc mentions:

> Your app invokes an exact alarm to complete an action that the user
> requests.

Does this mean that the usage scenario below can work?

1. Use `AlarmManager.setAlarmClock` to schedule an exact alarm to trigger at time A. The alarm carries a `pendingIntent` that targets a registered broadcast receiver.
2. Time A hits, the receiver gets the intent.
3. In the receiver `OnCreate` method, we attempt to `startForegroundService`which involves displaying a sticky notification and playing custom music with `MediaPlayer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have implemented and tested this and it appears to be working, so I assume this is a valid use case.

Comment: Could you share an example? I keep getting the crash even when I am doing the same as you asked in the question.

Comment: @theimpulson I can't paste all the codes here (and I'm using Xamarin). But some things to check: 1) You have declared the `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` and `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` permissions in manifest 2). You have registered your alarm trigger broadcast receiver 3) You have registered your foreground service 4) In your foreground service's `onStartCommand`, you must call `startForeground`  asap to display a notification before performing other tasks. If you still have issues, you can paste your exact errors/exceptions and your codes here and maybe we can take a look.